# How to show contextmenu on inflated view?

Tags: android, view, contextmenu

I want to display contextmenu for an inflated view. Here is the code sample:

for grid_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
    <ImageView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:antialias="true" />
```

Now I am using it in my activiy class as:

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {       
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select action");       
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Action1");
            menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Action2");

            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               registerForContextMenu(v);
                       openContextMenu(v);
            }

        });
```

This code runs without any error but the context menu does not show up when I click the imageView. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this situation and solved my problem.
As I told that the same code works fine and displays the ContextMenu, if I define the ImageView in the XML which I set in setContentView() method. I simply used the object of that imageView to register the contextMenu and displayed the ContextMenu on click of inflated item. Here is the sample code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {       
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select action");       
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Action1");
            menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Action2");

            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    ImageView imageViewInContext = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_in_main_xml);
    registerForContextMenu(imageViewInContext);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                 openContextMenu(imageViewInContext);
            }

        });
```

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

Add in your code:

```
imageView.setFocusable(true);
imageView.setClickable(true);
```

after that Imageview will get clickEvent.

Comment: Imageview is getting click event and executes the code inside onclickListener but still contextMenu does not show up.

Comment: Same code works fine, if I define the ImageView in the XML which I set in setContentView() method. But I need to do it on inflated view.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating an Anonymous Inner Class (by doing `new View.OnClickListener`) you are no longer operating in the UI thread (your Activity class), so the context menu does not load when you want to `registerForContextMenu` and `openContextMenu`. You can either use a `Handler` to send a message to the UI thread(your Activity class) to perform these actions, or try to reference your Activity class in your inner class. Something like this:

```
activityClassName.this.registerForContextMenu(v);
activityClassName.this.openContextMenu(v);
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but not working. Same code works fine, if I define the ImageView in the XML which I set in setContentView() method. But I need to do it on inflated view.

Comment: In that case, it seems that your idea of inflating is not working properly. Given imageView is a widget,I dont think you should be using a LayoutInflater for it. Have u tried View's static method View.inflate? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)