# Get context of PopupMenu like ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, expandablelistview, onclicklistener, popupmenu

So my `ExpandableListView` has group rows that are defined like :

**group_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/GroupName"
        style="@style/ListViewRowStyle"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/default_content_description_text"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When you click on the `TextView` it will expand or collapse depending on whether or not the child rows are currently displayed.  I have attached an `OnClickListener` to the `ImageView` in the group row.  When this `ImageView` is clicked I launch a `PopupMenu` like the images below :

[image]

[image]

Once the `PopupMenu` is displayed and one of the actions is clicked, I would like to perform an action on all children of the group.  The problem is that I cannot determine the row in which the `ImageView` was clicked.

The only way I have figured out how to apply an action to all children is with a `ContextMenu` like the image below :

[image]

I want to avoid using a `ContextMenu` because a LongClick on a group row may not be obvious for a user to figure out that it would bring up some actions to perform on the children rows.  I think the more obvious design is to anchor a `PopupMenu` to an `ImageView` (in my case a menu icon) and have the action be applied to the children rows of that group.  How can I get this functionality with a `PopupMenu` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out that in order to have some context of which menu icon was clicked, I utilized the [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object))  and [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag(int)) methods of the `View` class and just applied these methods to the `ImageView` (menu icon).

Comment: Even though it's been over a year since you posted this, I solved this differently and kept using the contextView, but if the view attached matched a certain ID i'd convert it to a popup.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407722/how-to-cancel-the-creation-of-a-context-menu-after-oncreatecontextmenu-has-bee/24014727#24014727

Check my answer here if you're interested. (And let me know if I'm an idiot)

Answer (score 4):

You need:

- A `View` where to inflate the PopUpMenu (your `ImageView`)
- A `PopUpMenu` saved in res/menu, in this case `popup_select_deselect.xml`
- Your own `onMenuItemClickListener` declared as internal class, in this case `onMenuItemClickListener_View`

Code:

```
//TODO initialize rows[]
for (int i = 0; i < rows.lenght; i++){
    //inflate you group_row
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.group_row, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.rows_container)); 

   ImageView v_Overflow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Menu);

   //Set onClickListener
   v_Overflow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    View v_Button = v;
                    PopupMenu pum= new PopupMenu(YourActivity.this, v);

                    //set my own listener giving the View that activates the event onClick (i.e. YOUR ImageView)
                    pum.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new onMenuItemClickListener_View(v) );
                           //inflate your PopUpMenu
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_select_deselect, pum.getMenu());
                    pum.show();

                }
            });


    //Update the id of your TextView
    .setId(i); //the i value will be your UNIQUE id for the ImageView

}
```

The code above is only a static declaration of what your own `OnMenuItemClickListener` will do.

Pay attention to the given `View` in the constructor of the following listener. When you create an instance of this listener, the `View` Id is the same declared in the XML layout. At runtime it will be updated, so when the method `onMenuItemClick` will be called, the `TextView` ID is already changed.

Here's the code:

```
private class onMenuItemClickListener_View implements OnMenuItemClickListener{

    View v_View;

    public onMenuItemClickListener_View(View v){
        v_View=v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        int i = v_View.getId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.popupItemSelectAll:
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Popup Select All for View #: " +  rows[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //TODO your code to select all
                return true;
            case R.id.popupItemDeselectAll:
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Popup Deselect All for View #: " + rows[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //TODO your code to deselect all


            return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```